# How to get touch for specific item in canvas point

Tags: android, android-canvas, point, ontouchlistener

I have canvas and 3 points that I want to drag on touch event. Here is my code.

```
public class Canvas7 extends View {

    Paint p;
    PointF point1;
    PointF point2;
    PointF point3;

    public Canvas7(Context context) {
        super(context);
        p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setStrokeWidth(3);

        point1 = new PointF(150, 200);
        point2 = new PointF(150, 500);
        point3 = new PointF(250, 300);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawARGB(80, 102, 204, 255);

        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        canvas.drawCircle(point1.x, point1.y, 10, p);

        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        p.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        canvas.drawCircle(point2.x, point2.y, 10, p);
        canvas.drawCircle(point3.x, point3.y, 10, p);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        if (x > 0 && y > 0) {
            if ((x < (point1.x + 20) && x > (point1.x - 20)) && (y < (point1.y + 20)) && y > (point1.y - 20)) {
                invalidateCanvas(event, point1);
            } else if ((x < (point2.x + 20) && x > (point2.x - 20)) && (y < (point2.y + 20)) && y > (point2.y - 20)) {
                invalidateCanvas(event, point2);
            } else if ((x < (point3.x + 20) && x > (point3.x - 20)) && (y < (point3.y + 20)) && y > (point3.y - 20)) {
                invalidateCanvas(event, point3);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void invalidateCanvas(MotionEvent event, PointF point) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            point.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            invalidate();
        }
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            point.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
            invalidate();
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

The code is not working. When I click on point and want to move it, it not moves. When I remove the `if((point.x) == x || (point.y) == y)` check I can move the point, but when I remove the check all points move together. So I want to drag only one point. 
For example if I touch on `point1`, I want to move only `point1` and nothing more. When I click on `point2` I want to move only point2.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please don't invalidate your question by editing it into a solved state. Doing so invalidates your question for future readers.

Comment: Please don't edit my comments :) I don't know why, but I lost some of my reputation.

Comment: I [can edit your posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), and to be quite direct, you can't tell me not to. The edits aren't destructive (although yours were), and otherwise follow meta conventions and other rules. And while I don't get any reputation for editing, [this is also closely related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385370/6296561).

Comment: I understand you can edit my questions. But why you're giving downvote to my questions or mark duplicate? Before asking question here, I'm searching in internet and if I can't find the solution I'm asking here. I know maybe a question like the question I ask already exist, but there's no solution for my problem. But some people like you are marking my questions duplicate. And because of that I notice in my question that 'this question is not duplicate, please don't give downvote or mark as duplicate'.

Comment: Please Zoe I think you're a good person and you can understand me. We're humans, we need to help each other))

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/6296561). Also, votes are private . You never know who downvoted, and that's by design. Dupe closing is [a fundamental part of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). [Votes are too](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote). Asking for your question to be excluded from moderation is not how the site works.

Comment: Understood. Ok thank you, good luck. Be happy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code basically fine if you have 1 pixel size fingers and you are able to touch the exact position where you placed a point. :)

So, you have to introduce a logical area around points and working with them. For example a circle is a good representation for points. If you touch the screen and you get the `x`, `y` coordinates, you just have to check which point is the closest one and also check the distance.

Steps:

1. If `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` is true:

   - You would check which point is the closest one within 10dp (radius of the logical circle)
   - If you found it, you would save as last reference point to know which is in moving state
2. Elseif `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE` is true:

   - If you have saved reference point which is in moving, then change the point's coordinates and invalidate UI
3. Elseif `event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` is true:

   - You clear the saved reference point, drag ended

Comment: I cleaned and edited my code. I replaced 'onTouch' with 'onTouchEvent', because I don't know why, but 'onTouch' not worked (not called at all). So I used 'onTouchEvent'. Also I made some changes in if statements, but it's not working too.

Comment: You upgrade your code to this: `x == (point1.x + 10) && y == (point1.y + 10)`
But this is just shift the coordinate and you also use equality instead of `<` or `>` to use range. It doesn't mean distance. You need to calculate with a point (touch point) and a circle (around points) where you need to detect a point it is inside of circle or not. Distance between center of circle and another point which less then then radius of circle means your point inside of circle. Distance between 2 points: https://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Distance-Between-Two-Points

Comment: I'v done something like this, but it's not work good yet. When I drag very fast, it stops dragging)). That's because of the range 20px that I add in if statement. I edited my question. Thank you.

Comment: Yes it is, but your are on the right way. This is the reason why I used this detection only when DOWN action happen. You have to detect only on first touch (at ACTION_DOWN) and save which point is touched.  Then you should move only this save point during MOVE event. And that's all. If you read my post again I'm sure you will understand my steps.

Comment: So in your latest code with 20 pixel threshold to detect which point touched looks fine, but it's enough do this only when action DOWN. Because this is the detection of which point dragged by user. Later, when user moves the dragged point it's not necessary detect again because you already know the dragged point. UP action means user released.

Comment: I updated my code. It works fine already, thank you very much :)